# Drawing a new circle bitmap at the click location while preserving previously drawn circles

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I am trying to draw circles using Bitmap.

Each time I click the mouse, the circle I previously drew is moved to the new position.

What I want to happen is: Each time I click the mouse, a new circle is created/drawn at the position I clicked and all previously drawn circles remain without moving.

I am working with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace multirectangle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }
    Bitmap background;
    Graphics scG;

    Rectangle rectangleObj;

    private Point clickCurrent = Point.Empty;
    private Point clickPrev = Point.Empty;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        rectangleObj = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
        scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clickCurrent = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        clickPrev = clickCurrent;
        if (clickPrev == Point.Empty) return;
        rectangleObj.X = clickPrev.X - rectangleObj.Height / 2;// +radius; 
        rectangleObj.Y = clickPrev.Y - rectangleObj.Width / 2;
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Draw(), 0, 0);

    }
    public Bitmap Draw()
    {
        Graphics scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        scG.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
        scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectangleObj);
        return background;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Remember the program has no idea what you drew last frame. You'll need to keep a list of positions most likely and then draw them all every frame.

Comment: This `scG.Clear` always clears the bitmap. Delete it and report back. Also note that this is somewhat convoluted, to put it mildly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your English was a little confusing. If I'm understanding your problem correctly, right now the only thing that's being drawn is the new circle where the click was, and you want all the old ones to persist as well?  In which case, there are two options:

1. Don't clear the bitmap before you draw. `scG.Clear(SystemColors.Control);`  will clear the bitmap you just drew.  If you remove that line and don't clear the bitmap, then the next time you click, it will then draw the new ellipse right on top of the last bitmap.
2. If you want a fresh drawing/bitmap everytime, you would need a list of your `rectangleObj` .  Each time you click, you add that point to your `rectangleObj` collection. Then in your draw method, you would iterate through the collection and draw all of them.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, you are right my English is not the best..and you got what I need ..Method one will not meet my needs, method 2 is more realistic and I thought about it.but because I am new to c# I don't know the coding procedure to apply it ..for example I want to make a list of rectangle0bj allow me to draw 100 circles .. how can I do that??

Comment: In your class, you want a member that's a container of rectangles. A simple example is the list. Add : `List<Rectangle> rectangleList`  Then in your mouse down once you get your rectangleObj, add it to the list: `rectangleList.Add(rectangleObj)` .  Now in the draw thread, you iterate through the list and draw each one. A simple way `for (int i = 0; i < rectangleList.Count; i++)  {  scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectangleList[i]);  } `

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments, I solved the problem using the second method..but now I am facing a new problem is the code running too slow ..please take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843054/which-part-of-the-code-make-c-sharp-running-too-slowand-is-it-something-fixab

Answer (score 1):

I notice a few things. First, in `Form1_MouseDown()`, you have this:

```
clickCurrent = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
clickPrev = clickCurrent;
```

You are overwriting the old position (`clickPrev`) before you even save it. If you want to keep both positions, you should put them in a simple structure, like a List. When you get a new point, just `Add()` it to the list. Then, in your `Draw()` routine, loop over all the elements in the list and draw them all.

If you just want two positions--and only two--just swap your statements like this:

```
clickPrev = clickCurrent;
clickCurrent = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

And you'll have to allocate another rectangle object for the drawing, although it would make more sense to take care of this in the `Draw()` routine.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the position of the following statements

```
clickCurrent = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
clickPrev = clickCurrent;
```

I think you are assigning the `clickCurrent` to `clickPrevious` after you initialize `clickCurrent`. It needs to be the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Rectangle rectangleObj;
Bitmap background;
Graphics scG;
Pen myPen;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangleObj = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
    background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
    myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);

    BackgroundImage = background;
}

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    rectangleObj.X = point.X - rectangleObj.Height / 2;
    rectangleObj.Y = point.Y - rectangleObj.Width / 2;

    scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectangleObj);
    Refresh();
}
```

`OnPaint` and `Draw` methods removed. As well as `clickCurrent` and `clickPrev` fields.

When you change the form size (for example, maximize it), Bitmap and Graphics remain the same, so you get this effect. To avoid this, you need to add the event handler

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
    BackgroundImage = background;
}
```

Note that each time you resize the form, all previously drawn is erased. If this is undesirable, a different approach is needed for drawing. Let me know, I will give another example.

Comment: thank you for trying, but this code will give me several circles can be drawn at same time and have a fixed distance from each other.. this is useful but unfortunately not for what I need to do.

Comment: @user6425922 - I don't understand you. The code does exactly what you wanted. I can assume that you change the form size during the work, right?