# Which part of the code make Drawing on bitmap slow...C#

Tags: c#

Code running slow.. the code generates multiple circles have a center can be specified by first click then change the radius by moving the pointer to desired circle size then click to finish drawing the circle.. and repeat to draw another circle..I solved the problem by very simple step see the comments down

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class Seat
    {
        private string _SeatKey;
        private Rectangle _SeatRectangle;

        public Seat(string seatKey, Rectangle seatRectangle)
        {
            _SeatKey = seatKey;
            _SeatRectangle = seatRectangle;
        }

        public string SeatKey
        {
            get { return _SeatKey; }
        }

        public Rectangle SeatRectangle
        {
            get { return _SeatRectangle; }
            set { _SeatRectangle = value; }
        }
    }

    List<Seat> _Seats = new List<Seat>();
    List<Seat> _center = new List<Seat>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i = i + 1)
            {
                string mystring = "regctangle" + i.ToString();
                _Seats.Add(new Seat(mystring, new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50)));
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i = i + 1)
        {
            string mystring = "center" + i.ToString();
            _center.Add(new Seat(mystring, new Rectangle(50 , 50 , 3, 3)));
        }
    }

    Bitmap background;
    Graphics scG;
    private Point clickCurrent = Point.Empty;
    private Point clickPrev = Point.Empty;
    int clikno = 1;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    int clicknew = 0;
    int radius=0;
    int recH;
    int recW;
    int xcen;
    int ycen;

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        clikno = clikno + 1;
        clicknew = clicknew + 1;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Draw(), 0, 0);

    }

    public Bitmap Draw()
    {
        Graphics scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 1/2);
        Pen mPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 3);
        scG.Clear(SystemColors.Control);


        _Seats[clikno].SeatRectangle = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, recH, recW);
        _center[clikno].SeatRectangle = new Rectangle(xcen, ycen, 3, 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < clikno+1; i = i + 1)
        {
            scG.DrawEllipse(myPen, _Seats[i].SeatRectangle);
            scG.DrawEllipse(mPen, _center[i].SeatRectangle);

        }
        Refresh();//This what cause the code running slow
        return background;

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoSize = true;

        clickCurrent = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        clickPrev = clickCurrent;

          if (clickPrev == Point.Empty) return;

            Refresh();
             clickCurrent = Point.Empty;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        double oradius = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(clickPrev.X - e.X, 2)) + (Math.Pow(clickPrev.Y - e.Y, 2)));
        radius = Convert.ToInt32(oradius);

        if (clicknew == 1)
        {

            recH = radius;
            recW = radius;
            xpos = clickPrev.X - recW / 2;
            ypos = clickPrev.Y - recH / 2;
            xcen = clickPrev.X - 3 / 2;
            ycen = clickPrev.Y - 3 / 2;
            Refresh();
        }
        if (clicknew == 2)
            clicknew = 0;
        Refresh();

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be more of a code review question. There's an SO site devoted to that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: You should not do anything unconditionally in MouseMove as if happens extremely often. Add sensible check like 'if the location has changed by at least 2 pixels' or something like that.. also: Your code always draws into a bitmap and then draws the bitmap. This is, of course extermely inefficient. (just compares how many pixels you draw with no reason at all!) Instead you should, as you have been told before collect all the rectangles you want to tdraw in a Listy<yourRectClass> and draw them in the paint event to the surface.

Comment: Which part is slow?  The constructor?  The drawing?  Loading the background image?

Comment: ..Drawing hundreds of Rectangles is extermely fast compared to drawing even one of your Bitmaps.

Comment: to add, in your upper loops just put it into one. :)

Comment: Seems odd that you'd be calling `Refresh` twice in your mouse move handler . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The part that is so slow is your `MouseMove`.**

Usually one checks for the left mousebutton to be pressed:

```
private void yourDrawingControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left) )
    {
        // draw stuff
    }
}
```

If that is not a condition that applies you should check for having moved for at least more than one pixel:

```
Point oldLocation = Point.Empty;

private void yourDrawingControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int minStep = 3;
    if ( (Math.Abs(oldLocation.X - e.X) +  Math.Abs(oldLocation.Y - e.Y) > minStep) )
    {
        // draw stuff
    }
    oldLocation = e.Location;
}
```

**Also**: While the graphics is being built up, do not draw into a `Bitmap` which you then draw with `DrawImage` in your `Paint` event. Instead in the `Paint` event draw directly onto the surfce of the control from a `List<yourDrawingshapeClass>` !

Drawing hundreds of `Rectangles` is extremely fast compared to drawing even one of your `Bitmaps`..

**Also**: It looks as if you are drawing onto the `Form`? Better draw onto a dedicated control with just the right size; the natural choice is a `PictureBox`, which is made for this and is **double-buffered** out-of-the-box. Instead your **enforce** the form to refresh **all** it controls..

**Finally**: Even if you refuse to change your convoluted code to something well-proven, at least make it not call `Refresh` in the `MouseMove` **unconditionally** (in the last line), even if nothing at all has changed!

Comment: The solution is very simpler than what i thought only one step,  get rid of the `Refresh()`  at the  `public Bitmap Draw()`  and will be super fast .. no need to do any thing else in the code ..Thank you for answer.it was very helpful information..